# Dynamodb stream lambda trigger data being received is missing a field

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

The dynamodb has 23 fields but what we received is only 22 fields on the lambda trigger event there is a missing attribute being received by the lambda function.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question, and you haven't provided much information here. Please review the StreamViewType for this DynamoDB stream (per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_StreamSpecification.html) and see if data written to the stream matches the documentation. If not, then please provide more details.

Comment: The StreamViewType is a NEW_IMAGE. And we're getting the data on the NewImage Field on the dynamodb Stream. What could be the cause of this? It is occurring intermittently in production environment. But on our lower environment we're not able to replicate it. And by the way our staging environment has the same settings as the production environment.

Comment: It has been solved now. The problem is on our blue-green deployment we are still sending traffics on our old stacks. And that's the cause.

Comment: Good debugging, glad you found the root cause quickly. You should write that up as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on our blue-green deployment we are still sending traffics on our old stacks. And that's the cause.